# How can I disable ESC key when Browser in full-screen mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullscreen

In my Vueproject,I use a full-screen components on "ace edit" which with the vim mode, but when press `ESC` or `ctrl+[` the full-screen mode will exits,so how can I resolve this problem. thanks!

[image: fullscreen exits when press esc]

Comment: I suggest not to do it. It is an accessibility consideration.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is validate the keypress, so like...

```
function logKey(e) { 
   if(e.code === "esc"){
   // do something
   }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

I haven't used Vue but for sure it has that event. Haven't tested it, by the way.

Comment: thanks for your response,i have try it but it dose not work,when in fullscreen mode i cant get the keyup event...